# How to avoid using Reflection with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I made a RecyclerView and I want to populate each item in the RecyclerView with different data (A view will be given Text data from Resources `String.xml` and Images from Resources `Drawable`). Each string in `String.xml` is named cat1...cat2...catn to fit into RecyclerView items 1...2...n.

The method I am using uses a lot of Reflection, is there another way that I can't figure out that is more efficient and less expensive? The whole point in me using RecyclerView was that it was less expensive!!

This method finds the ID for a specific string name

```
    public static int getStringIdentifier(Context context, String name) {
     return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName());
    }
```

This method builds the resource name based on the id for the position in the RecylerView. Gets the Id by calling the method posted above, then the string then sets it

```
    public void bind(int index){
        String resourceName = ("cat"+ (index + 1));

        int ResourceId = getStringIdentifier(mContext, resourceName);
        String catNameTitle = mContext.getResources().getString(resourceId);
        test.setText(catNameTitle);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how many items will be displayed in the `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [string-array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) instead of string to get a list of cat's name.

In your strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="cats">
        <item>Cat1's name</item>
        <item>Cat2's name</item>
        <item>Cat3's name</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Get the list of cat and inject the list to the `RecyclerView.Adapter` (or simply get it when initializing the adapter).

```
String[] catNames = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cats);
```

Then, in you `bind(int)` method:

```
public void bind(int index) {
    test.setText(cats[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this method into your recyclerview for stop reflecting items

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
```